# Proxy URL redirection using perl

Tags: perl, proxy, perl-module, http-redirect

I want to Do a proxy redirect from perl. I have been using Location Header to redirect.

```
    print ("Location: http://www.example.com\n");
```

The problem with this is the url on the client side changes to a new one (i.e. www.example.com ). I don't want that to happen, so that the end user is unaware of the location we are serving the request from.

Comment: Do you want to be a proxy or redirect the client? "Proxy redirect" makes no sense.

Comment: I would want to redirect the user to a different url, however the end user should not be able to see that in his browser. Basically I want to mock what we can achieve in .htaccess using Rewrite i.e.   `Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/%1? [R=302,P] `  Here I am able to redirect the user to a different url without the user getting to know about it.. Can we do this in perl?

Comment: Your RewriteRule example would in fact redirect the user with a 302 redirect.  If you don't want the user to see the location change in their browser, you'll need to fetch the content from the desired URL yourself, and send it to the user's browser (beware that relative links/images etc won't work unless you fix them up), or output a frameset that loads the content within a frame so that the address bar contains the URL of your script still.

Comment: Actually, looking again, your RewriteRule is using "P" to proxy, and also R=302 to redirect.  That makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the client is going to do the fetching, it's going to show the URL it's fetching unless the page being fetched is embedded in another page (e.g. by using an iframe). And even then, it's very easy for the user to discover the url if they look.

If instead you do want to a be a proxy (and by all indication you are), which is to say you want to fetch a doc and return it to the client, well, you have to start by fetching the doc you want to return to the client.

Note that you can configure apache to act as a [proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Right now I am achieving this by doing an implicit redirection in my perl program to a different folder.  `print ("Location: /cgi-bin/test/hello.cgi?".$name."\n");`  And then using .htaccess file in that folder to do a proxy rewrite.  `Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/%1? [P]`  My question was instead of doing this, can we redirect directly from the perl code without end user knowing about this redirection.

Comment: "P" cause Apache to act as a proxy, which is to say to fetch a doc and return it. Yes, you can do that in Perl. You have to start by fetching the doc you want to return to the client. And then you return it by printing the appropriate HTTP headers and then printing by doc itself.

Comment: ok. So what you mean is instead of Apache acting as a proxy and fetching a doc, our perl program would act as a proxy and fetch the document by reading the entire file and printing it out. Any suggestion on what would be the better approach as far as performance is concerned?

Comment: Most of the time would be spent waiting for a response. I'm not sure the speed of the code make that much of a difference. And with an nph script, you don't actually have to wait to get the whole thing before you start resending it. But we're talking about a significant amount of work, so if you can use apache instead, that would be great. With mod_perl (as opposed to CGI), you might have more options since you have access to apache's API.